# Throw car out of the circuit, based on its facing direction using physics

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was working on Car Wars game so I require throwing the car which crosses circuit boundary.

The following image depicts my point clearly:
[image]

Now as per my programming setup, I require throwing my car through force/velocity manually applied and I want to flip the car in the car throwing direction.

I have tried myself about this but didn't able to get the desired result.

```
myRigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * 80f);

Vector3 currentRotation = transform.eulerAngles.normalized;
myRigidbody.angularVelocity = new Vector3(currentRotation.x * Random.Range(1f, 4f), Random.Range(1f, 2f), currentRotation.z * Random.Range(1f, 2f));
```

Here are the car inspector settings:
[image]

Now share your side suggestion regarding this, I want to give force and angular velocity manually based on side of the circuit car diving.

Comment: 1. If you want to throw a car, I think you need another vertical force to fight the gravity.  2. If you wan to flip the car along x axis, why do you add y and z component of the angular velocity?  3. BTW what is the current behaviour?

Comment: @shingo if I write this line of code then at least car get thrown at correction direction.  myRigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * 200f); - Now I only get stuck on flipping of car based on its direction - what code to write for correct flipping?

Comment: @shingo Using this code - myRigidbody.angularVelocity = transform.forward * Random.Range(10f, 40f); - Car always get rotated in z-rotation not on x-rotation. Now I hope you can suggest me something to update.

Comment: Unity doesn't suggest to change angularVelocity directly, try `AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(Some Value, 0, 0), ForceMode.Impulse)`, try different force mode if it doesn't fit your purpose.

Comment: @shingo can you create the proper answer? because the above things worked for me for force and for car flipping too. So I can make this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AddRelativeTorque](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque.html) to apply an angular velocity along x axis:

```
rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(Some Value, 0, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
```

And [AddRelativeForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html) to throw the car forward.

```
rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(0, 0, Some Value), ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Comment: also in the answer, mentioned about forward force too - because I asked two questions in my above post. So one by one both get cleared.

Comment: Em but you said the forward force is okay to work, so I've do nothing with it, right?

Comment: But if you add the way for local forward force code then it will be better for future users otherwise they require to read our comments.